# C. recursion initializing a variable

Tags: c, recursion

my work:

```
#define SIZE 9
#include <stdbool.h>



bool arrayCheck(int arr[], int counter, int array_size);

void main() {
    int arr[SIZE] = { 1,2,5,1,5,1,2,3,4},num1=5;
    bool check= arrayCheck(arr, num1, SIZE - 1);

}

bool arrayCheck(int const arr[], int counter, int array_size) {

    if (counter == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (array_size < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (arr[array_size] - arr[array_size - 1] == 1) {
        counter -= 1;
        array_size -= 1;
    }
    else {
        counter = 5;
        array_size -= 1;
    }
    arrayCheck(arr, counter, array_size);
    
}
```

im writing a recursion function that should read an array and if there is a requested number of follow up numbers (defined by counter) the function will return "true" other wise the function will return "falls"
in my code the function works only if the the request amount of follow up numbers is 5 (cuz that was the number i was testing the function with) now im thinking if i can create and initiate a variable that wont re-initiate itself each time that would be the way. is it possible?

Comment: Just curious, why do you use recursion when a loop would be the straight forward thing to do?

Comment: The hard coded value `5` in line `counter = 5;` looks fishy...

Comment: @Jabberwocky Could be an exercise to translate the recusrive code to iterative

Comment: @Jabberwocky just an exercise, getting familiar with recurring functions. and yeah its something i need to change to a variable that should store the original value of  " counter" that i dont know how to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize a variable once and only once within the scope of a function, use the static keyword when declaring the variable.

For example, the counter variable below will only set to its initial value (0) once if defined within a function. Each subsequent call to foo will result in counter incrementing by 1. The first call will make counter = 1, 2nd call will make counter = 2, etc.

```
void foo( void )
{    
    static int counter = 0; 
    counter++;
}
```